# Find previous same value in a vector and apply certain conditions

Tags: r, for-loop

For each value of `myvector1` I would like to know the `mycategory` value of the immediate previous same value in `myvector1`, given that `mystatus` is *ON*, otherwise I would look for the corresponding next same value until it is *ON*.

Instructions would look like this:

1. For a given position of "myvector" give me his value.
2. Look for the position of the inmediate previous same value in
   "myvector"
3. Check the asssociated status. If it is ON give me his associated
   "mycategory". If it is OFF, repeat go to point 2.
4. Assign the obtained "mycategory" to a new vector "mysolution".

Given the dataset `mydf` What I am looking for is `DesiredSolution` (which I filled in manually).

```
mydf <- structure(list(myvector1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("0", "1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), mystatus = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("OFF", 
"ON"), class = "factor"), mycategory = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("bye", 
"hi", "stay"), class = "factor"), DesiredSolution = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("bye", 
"hi", "NA", "stay"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("myvector1", 
"mystatus", "mycategory", "DesiredSolution"), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With data.table...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)
mydf[, r := .I]
mydf[, v := mydf[mystatus == "ON"][mydf, on=.(r < r, myvector1), mult="last", x.mycategory]]
```

which gives

```
    myvector1 mystatus mycategory DesiredSolution  r    v
 1:         0       ON         hi              NA  1   NA
 2:         1      OFF         hi              NA  2   NA
 3:         2       ON       stay              NA  3   NA
 4:         3       ON        bye              NA  4   NA
 5:         4      OFF        bye              NA  5   NA
 6:         0       ON        bye              hi  6   hi
 7:         1       ON        bye              NA  7   NA
 8:         3       ON       stay             bye  8  bye
 9:         4       ON       stay              NA  9   NA
10:         1      OFF        bye             bye 10  bye
11:         2       ON         hi            stay 11 stay
12:         3       ON         hi            stay 12 stay
13:         4       ON       stay            stay 13 stay
14:         1      OFF        bye             bye 14  bye
15:         2       ON        bye              hi 15   hi
16:         4       ON        bye            stay 16 stay
17:         0       ON        bye             bye 17  bye
18:         1      OFF        bye             bye 18  bye
19:         2       ON         hi             bye 19  bye
20:         3       ON         hi              hi 20   hi
21:         4      OFF       stay             bye 21  bye
22:         0      OFF        bye             bye 22  bye
23:         1       ON        bye             bye 23  bye
24:         3      OFF        bye              hi 24   hi
25:         4       ON        bye             bye 25  bye
26:         0      OFF        bye             bye 26  bye
27:         0      OFF         hi             bye 27  bye
28:         1      OFF         hi             bye 28  bye
29:         2      OFF         hi              hi 29   hi
30:         3      OFF         hi              hi 30   hi
31:         4      OFF       stay             bye 31  bye
32:         2       ON       stay              hi 32   hi
    myvector1 mystatus mycategory DesiredSolution  r    v
```

*How it works:* Look up rows in `mydf[mystatus == "ON"]` where row number `r` is lower and `myvector1` matches. Return `mycategory`, taking the last matching row if there are multiple matches.

Comment: can you explain the 'last' argument and the `mult` parameter?

Comment: @bringtheheat In a join `x[i, on=]`, we're looking up each row of `i` in `x`. If there are multiple rows of `x` for a given row of `i`, `mult=` determines which of them are returned. If it's set to "last", it returns only the last matching `x` row (in the order of rows in `x`).

Comment: ah, got it. that is an elegant solution. typically use `data.table` for in-place manipulations so the `mult=` parameter will be nice to use. i can see it being really nice for data involving timestamps (assuming data sorted using `setorder()`.......)

Answer (score 3):

Another possible way, working with "slice" of your `data.frame` and `zoo::na.locf`

First, set the position of your data so you can get it back afterwards

```
mydf$pos <- seq_len(nrow(mydf))
```

Then `split` your data.frame according to `myvector1`:

```
spl_mydf <- split(mydf, mydf$myvector1)
```

Then apply to each "slice" (only one value of `myvector1`) a function which keep only the values of `mycategory` when `mystatus` is ON, put the rest as `NA` and replace `NA` with previous not `NA` value. The first item is `NA` and you don't keep the last item (in order to get the desired lag).

```
my_out <- lapply(spl_mydf,
                 function(sl_df){
                    out <- sl_df$mycategory
                    out[sl_df$mystatus=="OFF"] <- NA
                    data.frame(pos=sl_df$pos, 
                               out=c(NA, head(na.locf(as.character(out), na.rm=FALSE), -1))) # as.character is to avoid getting the factors levels
 })
```

Finally, put back everything according to position and suppress the pos column:

```
out <- do.call(rbind, my_out)
mydf$output <- out$out[order(out$pos)]
mydf$pos <- NULL

head(mydf, 10)
   myvector1 mystatus mycategory DesiredSolution output
1          0       ON         hi              NA   <NA>
2          1      OFF         hi              NA   <NA>
3          2       ON       stay              NA   <NA>
4          3       ON        bye              NA   <NA>
5          4      OFF        bye              NA   <NA>
6          0       ON        bye              hi     hi
7          1       ON        bye              NA   <NA>
8          3       ON       stay             bye    bye
9          4       ON       stay              NA   <NA>
10         1      OFF        bye             bye    bye
```

check everything is alright:

```
all(mydf$DesiredSolution==mydf$output, na.rm=TRUE) # TRUE
all((as.character(mydf$DesiredSolution)=="NA")==is.na(mydf$output)) # TRUE
```

(NA is considered as one of the levels in your data.frame)

Answer (score 1):

try this. i'm sure you can get it more terse.

```
DesiredSolution = vector()
for (i in 1:length(myvector1)) {
  step_1 = myvector1[i]
  step_2 = grep(step_1, myvector1)
  step_2 = step_2[step_2 < i]
  step_2a = sort(step_2, decreasing = T)

  if (length(step_2) != 0) {
    for (d in 1:length(step_2a)) {
      k = step_2a[d]
      step_3 = mystatus[k]
      if (step_3 == 'ON') {
        step_4 = mycategory[k]
        break
      } else if (step_3 == 'OFF' & d == length(step_2a)) {
        step_4 = NA
      }
    }
  } else {
      step_4 = NA
  }
  DesiredSolution = c(DesiredSolution, step_4)

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems to work properly. It creates a vector of n+1 length with NA in last position tough but I just remove last position.

Comment: try the new one i posted. i misunderstood the premise in the OP

Comment: you should look at the solution posted by @Frank , it's much more concise, faster, and more memory efficient (all educated guesses without actually benchmarking)